# Using JSON.stringify on object without serializer needs to be marked as experimental

Tags: android, json, serialization, kotlin

Using kotlin plugin 1.3.10 in Android Studio,
when I try to stringify a simple class' object to JSON, it wont compile:

This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer' or '@UseExperimental(kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer::class)'

```
@Serializable data class Data(val a: Int, val b: Int)
val data = Data(1, 2)
val x = JSON.stringify(data)
```

However, giving a serialiser works:

```
val x = JSON.stringify(Data.serializer(), data)
```

I can't see anybody else having this problem, any idea what the problem is? I've set up using serialisation in gradle.build.

I import with:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JSON
```

Comment: The error describes exactly what you need to do if you use experimental features. What's the question, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

The overload of `StringFormat.stringify` which doesn't take in a serializer (`SerializationStrategy`) is still experimental. If you view its definition (e.g. ctrl+click on it in the IDE) you'll see it looks as follows:

```
@ImplicitReflectionSerializer
inline fun <reified T : Any> StringFormat.stringify(obj: T): String = stringify(context.getOrDefault(T::class), obj)
```

Where that `ImplicitReflectionSerializer` annotation is itself declared in that same file (`SerialImplicits.kt`):

```
@Experimental
annotation class ImplicitReflectionSerializer
```

So because it's still experimental, you need to do exactly as the warning says, i.e. tell the compiler to allow the use of experimental features, by adding an annotation such as `@UseExperimental...` where you're using it.

Note that the [quick example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#quick-example) shown on the `kotlinx.serialization` GitHub repo's main readme shows that you need to pass in a serializer when calling `stringify`.

Comment: Ah, OK. All the examples using it didn't mention it. However, when I annotate the function that uses it with @UseExperimental... , then functions that call that need to be annotated as well, all the way up to the top level I think. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I just tried there and when I annotate `Class1.method1()` with `@UseExperimental` I can call it from `Class2.method2()` without annotating that second class/method with `@UseExperimental`. Are you getting different results?

Comment: In fact this is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-use-experimental/index.html):  "If a declaration is annotated with UseExperimental, its usages are **not** required to opt-in to that experimental API."

Comment: Thanks, just using. I was using

'@kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer' 
'@UseExperimental(kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer::class)'