# Is there better way for handle kotlinx serialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

I use `kotlinx.serialization` on Kotlin native project, I a defined `Super class` for my models and all of the models extends from it. 
I defined a `function` to called `toJSON()` for serialize variables and fields inside model that all of class models have it.

```
@Serializable
open class Model {
   fun toJSON(): String = JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

And I created a subclass

```
class Me : Model() {
  var name:String = "Jack";
}
```

but when I invoke `JSON.stringify(this)`, IDE get a Warning to me:

> This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer' or '@UseExperimental(kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer::class)'

I paid attention and I used `@ImplicitReflectionSerializer` annotation while not worked.
Where is my problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641364/using-json-stringify-on-object-without-serializer-needs-to-be-marked-as-experime/53656369). It's the particular overload you're using which is still experimental. So your options are either to use the other overload (which takes in a serializer) or to use one of the annotations mentioned in the error message. If you look at the answer to the question I linked (and the comments following it), you'll see it talks about using `@UseExperimental` and where it should be used.